# Duplicate words in a sentence

Tags: java, string, split

I wrote a small program in Java to find the duplicate words in sentence. No syntax errors, no complication error but I am getting a weird and long error as soon as I run it.

```
class Find {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String M = "Hello World Hello Hello";
        String[] words = M.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < M.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M.length(); j++) {
                if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(words[j])) {
                    System.out.printf("Duplicate Words :" + words[i], words[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running it:

```
Duplicate Words :HelloDuplicate Words :HelloDuplicate Words :HelloException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at Find.main(Find.java:9)
```

What wrong did I do ? Please help.

Comment: The error isn't all that weird.  You don't output a new line between your output lines, so they're getting all strung together.  The error message starts with `Exception in thread "main"` ...

Comment: @Lance Preston, I through another flavor so you can have the whole picture. hope you like my way too. good luck

Comment: @Lance Preston +1 for helping me to practice more lambda in java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you are using is terrible.

Consider something like this:

1. maybe force the input string to lower so that "hello" matches "helLo" when sorting.
2. split the string.
3. add the contents of the array, that is returned by split, to a List (maybe an ArrayList).
4. Sort the List.
5. Iterate through the List (exactly one time).  If you are not on the last element in the list and the current word is the same as the next word (remember, they are sorted) add the current word to a Set (maybe a HashSet).  When finished, the Set will contain all duplicated words.

Comment: Yes! Your suggestion is great :)

Answer (score 5):

You want to iterate limited by

```
words.length
```

not `M.length()`

Better to split and then use `HashSet<String>` `add(String)` method

that would be `O(n)`, your existing solution is `O(n^2)`

Comment: `words.length` in both loops :)

Answer (score 1):

**I know you have already had what you were looking for, yet I solve this in better way with less headache**

Code:

```
        String M = "Hello World Hello Hello helLo hEllo worLD";
        String[] words = M.split(" ");
        List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(M.split(" "));
        wordsList.stream().map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
                          .distinct()
                          .forEach( s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```

Output:

```
HELLO WORLD
```

Note: I used lambda in Java

imports are

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Comment: Yeah! :) I need to give some time to lambda :P

Comment: @LancePreston ya we should cuz functional programming is the future. plz keep in touch

Comment: Yes! Sure :) I always keep doing these experiments :D :P